# get the value sent with g:link on GSP

Tags: grails, gsp

```
<li><g:link params="[num: patientInstance.id]" controller="Consultation" action="create">creer consultation </g:link></li>
```

this g:link is in the patient view\show , i use it to send the id of the patient to the consultation controller in order to use it later ,so how can i get the patientInstance.id in consultation controller ?

thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `params` map.
http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/params.html

So in your `Consultation` `controller` you have your `create` action as such:

```
def create() {
    def patient = Patient.get(params.num.toLong())
...//do something else //

}
```

Then you have it render a view, or send a `map` back to the `gsp` with the name create.

Comment: Instead of `params.num.toLong()` you can just do `params.long(‘num’)`.  You could also skip that altogether and have the create action accept the value by defining the method as `def create(long num) { … }`, or you could skip that too and let the framework do the lookup by declaring that the action accept a `Patient` as an argument, `def create(Patient patient) { … }`. For that last one to work, the parameter should be named `id` instead of `num`.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I have seen some parameters being passed into actions, but was unsure from where they were passed, and didn't really have the time to dig into it as it didn't appear to be relevant to the things I was doing. Is it in the grails documentation somewhere?

Comment: "Is it in the grails documentation somewhere?" - Yes.  See the "Data Binding and Action Arguments" sub-section under http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer , i finaly found a solution to my issue .

i used the params map in the _form.gsp file in the consultation folder .
it was like that :

```
<g:select id="patient" name="patient.id" from="${com.test.Patient.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${consultationInstance?.patient?.id}" class="many-to-one"/>
```

this is what i did:

```
<g:select id="patient" name="patient.id" from="${com.test.Patient.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${params.num }" class="many-to-one"/>
```

:) happy codding